# Statistical functions in R dataframe (without sqldf package)

Tags: r

I have a data frame in R that contains values like the following:

```
  Est     Act     Tgt   Name
   34      45      42    Tom
   36      36      37    Tom
   39      38      38    Tom
   31      40      38   John
   35      41      40   John
```

For values corresponding to each distinct value in `Name` column, I want to gather some basic statistical values, to end up with something like the following:

```
        Min   Max    Avg    Min   Max    Avg
Name    Est   Est    Est    Tgt   Tgt    Tgt
 Tom    -11     1  -3.33     -3     1  -0.66
John     -9    -6   -7.5     -2    -1   -1.5
```

- `Min.Est` signifies the `minimum` (for a given name) of `Est minus Act` values
- `Max.Est` signifies the `maximum` (for a given name) of `Est minus Act` values
- `Avg.Est` signifies the `average` (for a given name) of `Est minus Act` values

Similarly:

- `Min.Tgt` signifies the `minimum` (for a given name) of `Tgt minus Act` values
- `Max.Tgt` signifies the `maximum` (for a given name) of `Tgt minus Act` values
- `Avg.Tgt` signifies the `average` (for a given name) of `Tgt minus Act` values

Not sure how helpful the `sqldf` package can be, but how can I do these calculations in `R` without using any package/library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Without external package**

From your example:

```
data <- read.table(text='Est     Act     Tgt   Name
34      45      42    Tom
36      36      37    Tom
39      38      38    Tom
31      40      38   John
35      41      40   John', header=T, stringsAsFactors=F)

data$E_A <- data$Est - data$Act
data$T_A <- data$Tgt - data$Act

data2 <- data[,c("Name", "E_A", "T_A")]
```

I create a function with the statistical functions, which can be adapted. (I add the standard deviation)

```
stat_summary <- function(data){
  data.frame(Min = min(data), 
             Max = max(data), 
             Avg = mean(data),
             Std = sd(data))
}
```

A function to work on each name:

```
group_by_name <- function(name, data){
  as.data.frame(lapply(data[data$Name == name, names(data) != "Name"], stat_summary))
}
```

And finaly my summary function

```
my_summary <- function(data){
  t(sapply(unique(data$Name), group_by_name, data=data))
}
```

And the output:

```
> my_summary(data2)
     E_A.Min E_A.Max E_A.Avg   E_A.Std  T_A.Min T_A.Max
Tom  -11     1       -3.333333 6.658328 -3      1      
John -9      -6      -7.5      2.12132  -2      -1     
     T_A.Avg    T_A.Std  
Tom  -0.6666667 2.081666 
John -1.5       0.7071068
```

**With external package**

Using `dpylr` and `tidyr`:

```
data %>% mutate(E_A = Est-Act, T_A = Tgt-Act) %>%
         gather("Type","Value",5:6) %>% 
         group_by(Name, Type) %>% 
         transmute(Min = min(Value), Max = max(Value), Avg = mean(Value)) %>% 
         distinct() %>% 
         ungroup() %>% 
         gather("Type2", "Value", 3:5) %>% 
         unite(Type, Type, Type2, sep = ".") %>% 
         spread(Type, Value)
```

give the output:

```
Source: local data frame [2 x 7]

  Name   E_A.Avg E_A.Max E_A.Min    T_A.Avg T_A.Max T_A.Min
1 John -7.500000      -6      -9 -1.5000000      -1      -2
2  Tom -3.333333       1     -11 -0.6666667       1      -3
```

Comment: You should start with `library(dplyr)`, and maybe address OP's desire for "without using any package/library".

Comment: @web-user modify his question by adding " without using any package/library" after I start to write my anwser.

Comment: @rconradin that's true... it was part of the title, but I did not really clarify the requirement in the actual question and modified it almost immediately.

Comment: The solution is quite fascinating, although I may not have access to the libraries you have used. I will explore the option and will up-vote your answer in the meantime. Thanks.

Comment: @rconradin I appreciate the solution provided, with and without external packages. The solution worked for me.

Comment: @rconradin I wanted to make the function `group_by_name` a bit more generic, so column names need not be hard-coded. I changed it to: `group_by_name <- function(name, colName, data) { as.data.frame(lapply(data[data[colName] == name, names(data) != colName], stat_summary)) }`. But I am not sure how to use this in the `my_summary` function, i.e. to be able to pass `"Name"` into the `colName` argument.

Comment: In `sapply` function, you add the arguments at the end. So: `my_summary <- function(data){  t(sapply(unique(data$Name), group_by_name, data=data, colName="Name"))}`

Comment: If you want a more generic version of the `my_summary` function, you can have this: `f <- function(data, colName){t(sapply(unique(data[[colName]]), group_by_name, data=data, colName=colName))}`

Answer (score 0):

Without using any extra packages, here's a good start:

```
by(your_data[1:3], your_data[[4]], summary)
```

Example using built-in data:

```
> by(iris[1:4], iris[["Species"]], summary)
iris[["Species"]]: setosa
  Sepal.Length    Sepal.Width     Petal.Length    Petal.Width   
 Min.   :4.300   Min.   :2.300   Min.   :1.000   Min.   :0.100  
 1st Qu.:4.800   1st Qu.:3.200   1st Qu.:1.400   1st Qu.:0.200  
 Median :5.000   Median :3.400   Median :1.500   Median :0.200  
 Mean   :5.006   Mean   :3.428   Mean   :1.462   Mean   :0.246  
 3rd Qu.:5.200   3rd Qu.:3.675   3rd Qu.:1.575   3rd Qu.:0.300  
 Max.   :5.800   Max.   :4.400   Max.   :1.900   Max.   :0.600  
------------------------------------------------------------------ 
iris[["Species"]]: versicolor
  Sepal.Length    Sepal.Width     Petal.Length   Petal.Width   
 Min.   :4.900   Min.   :2.000   Min.   :3.00   Min.   :1.000  
 1st Qu.:5.600   1st Qu.:2.525   1st Qu.:4.00   1st Qu.:1.200  
 Median :5.900   Median :2.800   Median :4.35   Median :1.300  
 Mean   :5.936   Mean   :2.770   Mean   :4.26   Mean   :1.326  
 3rd Qu.:6.300   3rd Qu.:3.000   3rd Qu.:4.60   3rd Qu.:1.500  
 Max.   :7.000   Max.   :3.400   Max.   :5.10   Max.   :1.800  
------------------------------------------------------------------ 
iris[["Species"]]: virginica
  Sepal.Length    Sepal.Width     Petal.Length    Petal.Width   
 Min.   :4.900   Min.   :2.200   Min.   :4.500   Min.   :1.400  
 1st Qu.:6.225   1st Qu.:2.800   1st Qu.:5.100   1st Qu.:1.800  
 Median :6.500   Median :3.000   Median :5.550   Median :2.000  
 Mean   :6.588   Mean   :2.974   Mean   :5.552   Mean   :2.026  
 3rd Qu.:6.900   3rd Qu.:3.175   3rd Qu.:5.875   3rd Qu.:2.300  
 Max.   :7.900   Max.   :3.800   Max.   :6.900   Max.   :2.500
```

If you want more help formatting, etc., please provide a reproducible example. Please also state your use-case - do you just want to see the info? Are you intending to store it in a data frame? Are you making a table for a report? I ask, because your desired output will not work well as a data frame - the main idea of a data frame is that each column should have a single class/type, that is no mixing of numbers and strings in a single column.

Comment: Once I get to point of the desired output, I just need to present the data in a report, although it may become part of further analysis subsequently, in which case it will need to be stored in a data frame (I suppose). But you are saying a data frame won't work because the Name column is string type whereas all other columns have numbers?

Comment: Your desired output would be fine for a data frame if the `name` was a column - it's fine to have a *column* of string type. The problem is that you have `name` as a *row*, which means your columns (e.g., `MIn`) have mixed types, strings in the `name` row and numeric in the other rows.

Comment: For report/printing, that's fine, we will just use strings for everything. For storing it as an R object, it would be better to use a data frame in long format (where `Name` is a column, not a row.

Answer (score 0):

This will give you the ungrouped values of those statistics:

```
 unlist( lapply( c("Est", "Tgt"), 
         function(coln) setNames( summary(my_df[[coln]]-my_df[["Act"]])[c(1,6,4)], 
                                  paste( coln, c('Min', 'Max', 'Avg'), sep="_"))))
Est_Min Est_Max Est_Avg Tgt_Min Tgt_Max Tgt_Avg 
    -11       1      -5      -3       1      -1
```

Now you need to use that strategy to do it by groups:

```
fn_stats <- function(dfrm) unlist( lapply( c("Est", "Tgt"), 
               function(coln) setNames(summary(dfrm[[coln]]-dfrm[["Act"]])[c(1,6,4)], 
                                   paste( coln, c('Min', 'Max', 'Avg'), sep="_")
                                 )      )) 
round( t(sapply( split(my_df, my_df$Name) , fn_stats) ),2)

#----result---
     Est_Min Est_Max Est_Avg Tgt_Min Tgt_Max Tgt_Avg
John      -9      -6   -7.50      -2      -1   -1.50
Tom      -11       1   -3.33      -3       1   -0.67
```